# PostgreSQL - Автоматическое преобразование типов

Tags: postgresql

Я работаю над портированием базы с Firebird на PostgreSQL и сталкиваюсь с множеством ошибок связанных с несовместимостью типов. Для примера возьмем одну простую функцию, на деле она может быть любой сложности:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_Concat3 (
  s1 varchar, s2 varchar, s3 varchar
)
RETURNS varchar AS
$body$
BEGIN
   return s1||s2||s3;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE CALLED ON NULL INPUT SECURITY INVOKER LEAKPROOF COST 100;
```

При вызове данной функции в контексте селекта из Firebird в аргументы можно передавать самые разные типы, Firebird автоматически превратит date/integer/float в строки и выполнит данную функцию.

У PostgreSQL же строгая типизация и при попытке вызвать данную функцию в виде: 
`f_Concat3 ('1', 2, 345.345)` выскочит ошибка:

> function f_Concat3(unknown, integer, numeric) not found.

Если первый аргумент с типом `unknown` postgres автоматически приводит к нужному строковому типу, то с вторым и третьим аргументом он уже не может справиться.

В документации рекомендуется использовать явное приведение, в этом случае
`f_Concat3 ('1'::varchar, 2::varchar, 345.345::varchar)` успешно сработает.

Альтернативно можно завести клоны функций со всеми возможными вариациями типов аргументов, но это явно плохой подход и не сработает для больших функций, поскольку внутри придется вновь следить за совместимостью типов.

А проблема состоит в том, что мы используем единую кодовую базу для всех СУБД и свой язык для построения форм и запросов приложения. Поэтому добавление явного приведения во все запросы с вызовом функций приведет к поломке совместимости с другими СУБД.

Меня смущает что `numeric` или `double precision` аргументу нельзя скормить `integer`, а обработчик не может превратить дату/число в строку автоматически. Вроде даже встречались проблемы преобразования `integer` в `smallint` и наоборот. У большинства СУБД с этим все хорошо.

Можно ли обойти данную проблему без явного приведения типов?

Comment: поэкспериментируйте с `any` типами https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-pseudo.html

Comment: @Mike это будет работать только если все 3 входных аргумента будут одинакового типа. Для данного примера.

Comment: А если внутри функции сделать уже явное приведение ? `return s1::varchar||s2:varchar...`

Comment: @Mike f_Concat3('a','b','c') не сработает, в данном случае он не сможет понять что делать с unknown константами. f_Concat3('1','1','1') тоже. 
f_Concat3(1,'1','1') сработает, он подогнал тип исходя из первого аргумента и все преобразовал к integer. f_Concat3(1,'1a','1') не сработает, ибо 1а не integer.